# Search bar works correctly but table doesn't show the results

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, searchbar

I'm trying to implement a search bar for my iOS 7 app.

The table view doesn't show the values when the filter is active, but the filter is correct.

So, I have all the results: 
[image]

Then, I started to filter the data with no valid result:

[image]

Finally, I used a valid filter and log result is correct, but the table doesn't show this:
[image]

I don't know how to find problem. My code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [self.searchResults count];
    } else {
        return [self.balancesData count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"balancesCell";
    BalancesTableViewCell *cell = (BalancesTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[BalancesTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Balances *balance = nil;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        balance = self.searchResults[indexPath.row];
    } else {
        balance = self.balancesData[indexPath.row];
    }

    cell.razonSocialLabel.text = balance.razonSocial;
    cell.importeLabel.text = balance.importe;

    tableView.backgroundColor =  cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.937 green: 0.937 blue: 0.957 alpha: 1.0];

    return cell;
}

    - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"razonSocial contains[c] %@", searchText];
    self.searchResults = [self.balancesData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller     shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar     scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Do you have prototype cells setup in storyboard?  I think you should dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier from self.tableView, not the tableView passed as a param.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Danh has given the right answer in his comment. The problem here is that you are saying:

```
cell.razonSocialLabel.text = balance.razonSocial;
```

But what if `cell` is *not* actually a BalancesTableViewCell? Then `cell.razonSocialLabel` is nil, `cell.razonSocialLabel.text` call `setText:` on nil, and nothing happens. So you are getting cells, all right, but they are all displayed as blank.

You need to obtain your cells from your *real* table; that is the table that hands out BalancesTableViewCell when you dequeue a cell. But instead you are obtaining your cells from `tableView`, which in the case of the filtered table is the *search display controller's* table view, which knows nothing of BalancesTableViewCell.

Thus, as Danh rightly says, you must change this line:

```
BalancesTableViewCell *cell = 
    (BalancesTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

to this:

```
BalancesTableViewCell *cell = 
    (BalancesTableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```